# Changing chapter style

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I am wondering how to change the chapter style to the following format?
[image]

I tried using `titlesec` package but couldn't figure out how to create this format.

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\chapter{introduction}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! Would you mind to upload a minimal working example that illustrates what you've tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: Is the small 1 on the first line important? it looks weird.

Comment: @cfr: It is not. That is the page number style, which I have already taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution using `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\fillast}{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter : #1}}{1ex minus .1ex}{\bfseries\uppercase}

\begin{document}
\chapter{introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the O.P.  wants a centred title, so the `block` style  and the `\filcenter` directive would probably be a better fit.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper. I am getting close to what I need with your solution. I need to push it up where the regular text begins and also I need to start from the left. Can you provide guidance on how to achieve this?

Comment: You could for example use `\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{*2.5}` and for left alignment, just delete `\fillast` like:

`\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{}{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter : #1}}{1ex minus .1ex}{\bfseries\uppercase}`